# Can't click Flash object in Firefox using Watir hover

Tags: firefox, watir, watir-webdriver

I am using Watir-webdriver to hover over a Flash object and then click that object.  The code that I am using works fine in Chrome and IE11 (Windows), but not on Firefox.

```
x.div(:id => "foo").hover
x.div(:id => "foo").click
```

Is there another way to perform this action as a workaround for Firefox?

Comment: Add html of this tag please and text of error from the Firefox

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue by simply adding a sleep timer before hovering over the object.  The new code is:

```
sleep 3
x.div(:id => "foo").hover
x.div(:id => "foo").click
```

It seems like the hover command was being executed before the object was fully loaded.